# Poblema en Creación de Dynamic Web Project en eclipse

Tags: java, web, eclipse

Se supone que al hacer el "scr" y el "content directory" aparecen llenos con el main y el web conten, pero ¿por que no me aparecen? y ¿Que tengo que hacer para que las carpetas por default funcione?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal parece que tu problema es sobre configuración de software. Este tipo de preguntas, por lo general no son bienvenidas en el sitio. En todo caso, hace falta mucha más información en tu pregunta para poder determinar el problema: versión de software, plataforma, SDK, etc. Saludos

Comment: No se my bien si lo instalaste mal o borraste alguna cosa se supone que deberia salirte src por defecto eso ya lo hace java al crear el dynamic web project